# MySQL retains password of earlier installation even after proper 'yum remove' & 'yum install'

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, centos5

I'm using MySQL-Server over CentOS. I `'yum remove'` the MySQL-server and then again `'yum install'` it.
When I tried setting up a new password for `'root'` using `'mysqladmin'`... it raised an error.
Some following up showed it still had earlier-installation's root credential working for it.

~~~~~

Trying some more stuff, I manually set `'old_password=0'` in `'/etc/my.cnf'` and then tried re-installing. It still had the earlier password working for it.

Comment: This is better suited for [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/) as it's a server software issue and not a programming problem.

Comment: @Francois : is there any mechanism to move this thread to ServerFault, if there is any moderator looking at this... please do it.

Comment: for time being, I got a work-around to fix the problem...

$yum erase mysql mysql-server

$rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

$yum install mysql mysql-server

$service mysqld restart

i.e. after un-installation the dir '/var/lib/mysql' need to be removed manually... and on re-installation do a 'service restart'.
And it allows you to set a password for root w/o picking up old configurations.

Still... the issue exists of why to do it manually.

Comment: mark the question as answered then?

Comment: I haven't marked it Answered... cuz the solution that I've opted for is kind of a hack or say non-standard method.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the mysql tables are not being removed/replaced when uninstalling/installing. I am not sure where they are located on CentOs (/var/lib/mysql?), but if you remove these manually, it should work.

Comment: no, the location of User's info i.e. the table data resides in  '/var/lib/mysql"/mysql/user.MDY' 

but removing just that file wouldn't work... it don't get recreated on re-installation if entire dir structure is present

Answer (score 1):

login to console as root using

su -
root password: ***_***

then move to the directory /var/lib/

using the command

cd /var/lib

now provide this command to delete the existing mysql database :

rm -rf mysql

This command will remove the existing database of mysql which also contains user table where the password for all mysql users are stored including the root.

After removing the database directory and all the associated files with it rum this command to reinstall mysql

yum -y install mysql-server

after installation you will have fresh mysql installed with default settings

and root will have no password.

You can go ahead from here.

This worked for me.

Comment: thanks dude, that I figure out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606869/mysql-retains-password-of-earlier-installation-even-after-proper-yum-remove/12782355#comment7798724_6606869

Comment: First time I tried, didn't work.  But I think because I did "yum remove mysql" instead of "yum remove mysql-server".  Also you might want to remove /etc/my.cnf before re-installing it.

Comment: @AbhishekKr dude accept the answer, that is the way to award people who answer.

Comment: @PJBrunet : yes that is a differnce

Comment: @kunal dude, the answer you gave is the thing I used initially before posting it as mentioned in my comment earlier on the Q. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606869/mysql-retains-password-of-earlier-installation-even-after-proper-yum-remove/12782355?noredirect=1#comment7798724_6606869

the main issue still is there, requiring manual hack-patch... Query was to know if there is anything to avoid it